# Embeds Request Via Javascript Not Showing in IE9 & IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have a site that has a series of embeds that users can use to insert the content they create  on the site into their own blogs, pages, whatever.

The code we have them use is

```
<script src="[EMBED PROXY URL]" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That code makes a call to the server and it returns something like

```
(function(){  
  document.write("<iframe src='[EMBED VIEW URL]' frameborder='0' id='item_id_width' name='item_id_width' scrolling='no' marginheight='5px' height='400' width='200'></iframe>")
})();
```

I can see my server getting the request made by the javascript code, but for some reason in Internet Explorer 9 & 10, the server returns a HTTP 406 error ("Not accetable").

**It does not return the 406 error in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari. Everything loads as expected in those browsers.**

I have scoured the internet and can't find anyone who's run into this. So if anyone has any suggestions on how I fix this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very likely hitting an instance of this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/27/http-406-not-acceptable-php-ie9-standards-mode-accepts-only-text_2f00_css-for-stylesheets.aspx

Look at the outbound `Accept` header in Fiddler or a similar debugger. Is it different when coming from IE than when coming from other browsers?

Comment: Yes, they're different.

Chrome's
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8

IE:
    Accept:application/javascript, */*;q=0.8

But the server returns javascript (note the document.write above)

Comment: There is `*/*` in the IE Accept headers it's just not showing for some reason in the comment above.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong request; look at the request that is resulting in a HTTP/406 response.

Comment: According to the IE dev tools that's the request that generates the 406. It's the request made by the `<script src="[EMBED PROXY URL]"  />` bit of code. 

I'm having to use Browser Stack to debug so don't really have access to other tools like fiddler and such.

Comment: I don't understand your first comment in response then. Are you saying that the server returns the HTTP/406 response for the SCRIPT tag's request **and** that response still contains the same JavaScript content?

Comment: Either way, however, you probably just need to fix whatever buggy serverside logic you have that doesn't realize that "application/javascript" is the proper MIME type for a script file. I suspect you may have masked the problem in your attempt to sanitize the question: What exactly does the "EMBED PROXY URL" string end with? Would I be correct in guessing that it's something like ".php" rather than ".js"?

Comment: Ah HA! This pointed me in the right direction. This is a Ruby on Rails app, so adding ```:format => :js``` to the end of the embed related routes that only return javascript fixed the problem. Thank you.